# Save button Id in hidden and reference later to change button html

Tags: jquery

Written classic ASP, a loop generates a list of buttons, each with an **unique Id** *"myButton001", "myButton002" etc.*  When the button is clicked, I capture the *id* in *jQuery* and save it to an `input type=hidden.`  Later, I want to get that hidden *button Id*, and use it to change the button text (html) to say something else.

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
$(".rsvpChange").click(function() {
  var thisMyBtnId = this.id;
  $("#hdnMyBtnId").val(thisMyBtnId);
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

// In the modal I have a btnRSVPChange that calls an Ajax process.
// on return from Ajax I want to change the button from hdnMyBtnId.
var buttonId = $("#hdnMyBtnId").val();
$(buttonId).html(rsvpChange); // this does not work.
```

So I'm looking for a way to retrieve the button Id and change the html button text.

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery, elements are found by id by prefacing the id with hash, eg, #MyID, so change to the following:

```
var buttonId = $("#hdnMyBtnId").val();
$("#" + buttonId).html(rsvpChange); // this might work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Jquery's **All Query Selector** requires **"#"** before *Id*

Try This

```
var buttonId = "#"+$("#hdnMyBtnId").val();
$(buttonId).html(rsvpChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps

```
var buttonId = $("#hdnMyBtnId").val();

$(document).find(`[id=${buttonId}]`).html(rsvpChange); //This will work :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the last line

```
  // Get the button that opens the modal
    $(".rsvpChange").click(function() {
      var thisMyBtnId = this.id;
      $("#hdnMyBtnId").val(thisMyBtnId);
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      modal.style.display = "block";
    });

    // In the modal I have a btnRSVPChange that calls an Ajax process.
    // on return from Ajax I want to change the button from hdnMyBtnId.
    var buttonId = $("#hdnMyBtnId").val();
    $("#"+buttonId).html(rsvpChange); // You need to update this
```